# Typescript function return type of the optional property as const with default

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How to return the same type of the parameter if passed to the function, else fallback to another required parameter?

```
const r = <Name extends string, R extends string>({
   name,
   resource
}: {
    name?: Name,
    resource: R
}) => {

   return {
// here the type of the "name" should be same as the Name if exist, else as R. As const
       name: (name || resource) as Name extends never ? R : Name,
       resource: resource
   }
}

// this way works. The returned type is {resource: "test", name: "test-name"}
const resource = r({resource: 'test', name: 'test-name'})

// But this way the returned type is {name: string, resource: 'test'}. 
// The type of "name" should be "test" since the name parameter is missing, but it returns string instead
const resource = r({resource: 'test'})
```

The returned parameter types should be some string as **const**, not only string. The name is optional. If exist - the type of the name property should be as the argument name as const, otherwise as resource as const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple; just allow `Name` to default to `R`:

```
const r = <R extends string, Name extends string = R>({
    name,
    resource,
}: {
    name?: Name;
    resource: R;
}) => {
    return {
        name: (name || resource) as Name,
        resource: resource,
    };
};
```

Note that `Name` is now second in the parameter list. That is because optional parameters cannot come before required ones.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATjAvDAPAJRgUwB5U2AEwhmjgEswBzAGhgDkBDAW0y13yJKnKqRjQB8ACgDeAKBiSYYZpmoSpcTBBABXOMDliAvgC4Y4qdNkB+fYxYBuBZKUr1m-WmvaAlEgEGb8TFHVgvIyMZFn0hENYAH0ifew1MdwZiCy0gxWU1eP07TM15I20XazEAehKYKAALMmIAdwYATxhakDgAawgAOhgAFUrWJT84MEwCCoaAB1YagxyHTH0AIjxoRdoIpZWoAFoIxe0xUEhYOfiARj44UVjchZhl5Sg141D7rd3ZRZg3YrKYACFVLAqjN6k0qgNfP5RuMpjAZiINlweDQbvN9AByLYY7SdUrlPqsKCTVggABm9z2JEqagANmMAEasB6rEgUTQVfovVgTBhwWR4BAzJg1CAUVEMoHwk5Q4bEUji+HHTAMAiHcDQNHxABMl2up0cb0eXx+YiAA)

Comment: The name in resource1 has a type "test" | "test-name" but it should be only "test-name"

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Ah well, I guess you do need an assertion then.